# Regular expressions issue with python due to values with brackets

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a very large string (300 MB+), and it has some garbage data in it that I need to clean up.  I am using Python 2.7 32-bit.

I didn't want to use the string operation `replace` because the file the user uses is only going to grow over time, so I am trying to use `re.sub` to replace the value of `[linender]` with a new line character like `\n` or `os.linesep`.

It seems simple enough to do, so my pattern is:

`re.sub('\[lineender]\b, os.linesep, text_value)`

This results in only one value being replaced in the whole string, which is wrong.

Sample Data:

`s = """A|B|3[lineender]E|F|2M[lineender]"""`

Any ideas on how I need to modify my regex to get this working?
I basically need to replace the bracket word with a new line character.

Comment: Remove the `\b`, use `re.sub(r'\[lineender]', os.linesep, text_value)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `\b` in a non-raw string literal is a backspace. If you use a word boundary `r'\b'`, it will require a word char (a letter, digit or an underscore) after `]`. In your case, I'd remove `\b` altogether:

```
re.sub(r'\[lineender]', os.linesep, text_value)
```

If you want to make sure there is no word char after `]`, you may replace `\b` with `\B`, but please make sure you are using the `r` prefix to make your string literal raw.

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/8BYN5z):

```
import re, os
text_value = """A|B|3[lineender]E|F|2M[lineender]"""
print('"{}"'.format(re.sub(r'\[lineender]', os.linesep, text_value)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the pattern as a raw string:

```
re.sub(r'\[lineender\]\b', os.linesep, text_value)
```

alternatively, you'll have to use `\\` (double backslashes):

```
re.sub('\\[lineender\\]\\b', os.linesep, text_value)
```

Comment: `]` doesn't need to be escaped.